# jqgrid inline edit beforeSubmit afterSubmit

Tags: jqgrid

I was wanting to get beforeSubmit working .

```
colModel: [...],
              onSelectRow : function(id)
                            {
                           alert("Hi");
                            },
beforeSubmit:function(postdata, formid) {
                             alert("In beforeSubmit"); 
                        },
```

I have `onSelectRow` firing but `beforeSubmit` won't fire. This is for a grid in inline edit mode.

Have I got it in the right place? I'm beginning to wonder if this method is only for form edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[beforeSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) exists only in case of the usage of [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing). You don't described which kind of work you want to do before sending the data to the server, but I suppose you can use [serializeRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing&s%5B%5D=serializerowdata#saverow) event in your case.

Comment: How can I validate the data in one column based on values in other columns in case of inline edit, if I am saving the data locally, before posting the whole grid data to server?

Comment: @b.g: It's not so simple and can depend on the version of jqGrid which you use. One way is the usage of `beforeSaveRow` callback, but one will have to read the data manually from the editing line. It seems to me the most simple way.

Comment: I have a column which can only have unique values through out the grid. I have taken care of this in the modal add-form but user can still edit the entries in that column (cell-edit ) and create duplicate entries.i am using `beforeSaveCell` but it is not working. How can I do this?

Comment: @b.g: It's better that you post new question where you describe all in details.  You wrote about **inline editing** in your previous comment, but you write about **cell editing** now. One don't mix different editing mode typically. You should include in the text of your question test data (inclusive rowid, which you use) and the version and for of jqGrid, which you use. Free jqGrid allows to define `editable` property as callback, which allows to make column editable for Add, but prevent editing in Edit or to allow editing in inline editing, but prevent in cell editing.

Comment: @b.g: I implemented the new callback `saveRowValidation`, which allows easy to implement final validation of the row, in free jqGrid (the fork of jqGrid, which I develop since the end of 2014). See the comment to the corresponding [commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/94b6218f451d62bb3fb1dc5c7b11383c906672ea) for details.